# How to change vector tile data in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

Use `MapBox` on the web. When I first load the vector tile I want to make him reload other vector tiles is still using this `layer id`.

It looks like geojson's `setData` and image of `updateImage`

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to change the data in the vector.

So, I want to ask
How do I change the request path in the vector and have the `MapBox` request the resource again and render it to the map.

Or I can change the resource source file, let the `MapBox` request again, and get new data to render on the map.

But I don't know how to implement it, how to get it done.

Or you have a better way, please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the effect I want to achieve is a weather carousel.
I will render the thunderstorm weather on the map.
Similar to https://www.windy.com
If you have seen a similar case or website, please leave a message and let me know.
If you can provide code to help, then I will be very grateful.

I see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/3621

so terrible to me.

Comment: this's my question on github : https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8244

Comment: I am going to close this question because I have found the answer I want. I hope that you can also use this method to solve the current problem. Can view my issue on github